# `cut`: selecting columns containing a string

Tags: text-processing, terminal, regular-expression, columns, cut

I have a big file with several columns on each line. I'm familiar with using `cut -f -d` to select specific columns by their number.

I checked the manual for `cut` and it doesn't seem that there's a way to regex match columns.

What I want to do specifically is:

- select the 2nd column of every line
- and also select all columns that contain the string "hello" (there may be none, if not it could be any column(s) and not the same column(s) for each line)

What's the most convenient terminal tools for this operation?

EDIT:

Simplified example

```
x ID23 a b c hello1
x ID47 hello2 a b c
x ID49 hello3 a b hello4
x ID53 a b c d
```

The result I would want is:

```
ID23 hello1
ID47 hello2
ID49 hello3 hello4
```

or alternatively:

```
ID23 hello1
ID47 hello2
ID49 hello3 hello4
ID53
```

To elaborate the example given:

- Columns are defined by one space
- whether or not "only print if the string is present" is not really important, I can just `grep` for "hello" if necessary
- we can assume the string "hello" will never be in column 1 or 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If one space at the end of the line doesn't hurt you much:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i==2 || $i~"hello") printf $i" ";print ""}' file

ID23 hello1 
ID47 hello2 
ID49 hello3 hello4 
ID53
```

This doesn't assume anything about the position of the "hello" string.

Comment: You can post process to remove the additional space character : `awk '{ ...}'   | sed 's, $,,'`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this will be possible using simple tools like `cut`. Or, at least, not easily. Here's a Perl solution:

```
$ perl -lane '$k=join " ",grep{/hello/}@F; print "$F[1] $k" if $k' file 
ID23 hello1
ID47 hello2
ID49 hello3 hello4
```

Which you could simplify by using `grep` first:

```
$ grep hello file | perl -lane 'print "$F[1] ", join(" ", grep{/hello/}@F)'
ID23 hello1
ID47 hello2
ID49 hello3 hello4
```

#### Explanation

The `-n` option tells `perl` to read its input line by line and apply the script given by `-e`. The `-l` flag adds a newline (`\n`) to each `print` call. The `-a` option makes `perl` split its input lines on whitespace into the array `@F`.

So, the script itself is looking for all elements of `@F` (all columns) matching `hello` and saving them as the space-separated string `$k` (`$k=join " ",grep{/hello/}@F;`). Then, the 2nd field (`$F[1]`) and `$k` are printed if `$k` is defined, if at least one `hello` was found.

The second version is the same except that we don't need `$k` and print directly since we know that at least one `hello` will always be present.